# AngularJS + Phonegap app: Views fill 100% height

Tags: css, angularjs, cordova, topcoat

I'm building an android app with phonegap using angularJS + topcoat. I managed creating the index page, views and all the basic structure. My question is, there is some pages(partials) that doesn't have data to show. In that case, the view does not fill the height of the page. That makes a problem because I have a drawer menu hidden usin angular-snap. Because the page doesn't fill all the available height, the menu that is supposed to be hidden is visible. Does anybody know how to handle this situation? I'm attaching a image to examplify! [app-example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQWHs.jpg)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't use the css min-height property. Assume every page of your app is wrapped inside a div as follow :

```
<div classs="page">
  //your page content
  ...
</div>
```

You can then create the following CSS rule

```
.page {
  min-height :100%;
}
```

that will ensure that even if the height of your content is less than the total height of your screen it will occupy 100% of the page's height.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried that already and it didn't work. I also tried setting the min-height:100% on the body and html, also didn't worked.

Comment: Nicolas I solved the problem. I was setting the class on the partials div instead of setting on the "main" div with the ng-view directive. Now it works. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I managed solving the problem with Nicolas help. It didn't worked in the beginning because I was setting the new style on the partial's div. After trying for a while I set the class on the "main" div which holds the ng-view directive and it worked. Just an example in case others have the same issue:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl"> 
    <div snap-content snap-options="snapOpts" class="page">
        <div ng-view ng-class="slide"></div>
    </div>
</body>

.page {
   min-height :100%;
   background:inherit;
}
```

Note: I had to set a background for the page class otherwise it won't work.